# How to consistently take a picture using a voice command

Tags: camera, voice-command

Using a samsung galaxy s8, android version 8.0

I'm able to occasionally take pictures with "take picture" but it works about 25% of the time. If in selfie mode with the front camera and the camera app has identified a face with a yellow circle, "say cheese" seems to work about 33% of the time.

Comment: Update: Ok, I'm getting much better results with "say cheese" if I say it slowly and really enunciate. It the also works with either the front or the back camera.

Comment: Something is sporadically causing it not to work. I went out of the camera app and then back into it, was saying the command the same as before, and now it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

ok it turns out the actual commands are "smile", "cheese", "capture" or "shoot" to shoot a video.

Comment: So the lesson to be learned here is, as always, read your manual???